# Is this appositive?

Tags: clauses

Here's the sentence:
The men who died were members of the Batalion de San Patricio or the San Patricios, an artiller unit of the Mexican army, which saw action in the Mex-Am war.
I'm talking about the phrase " an artillery unit of the Mexican army,"
Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is a (non-restrictive) appositive.